# How to make the body occupy the whole page while using Vue.js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a login page using Vue.js for the first time, but I'm stuck trying to make the login page occupy the whole page. What should I do to set the height to 100%, since the CSS is being overwritten for some reason?

```
<template>
  <body>

    <div id="logo">
      Logo aqui
    </div>
    <hr width="1" size="500" style="0 auto" />
    <div id="login">
        <LoginForm />
    </div>
  </body>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import LoginForm from "@/components/login/LoginForm.vue";

export default {
  name: "LoginPage",
  components: { LoginForm }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

.line{
  border-left: 6px white;
  height: 500px;
  width: 6px;
}

html, body{
    height:100%; /*both html and body*/
}

body{
    margin: 0; /*reset default margin*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap:200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#153C66, #001B37);
}
</style>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe you can give try using **`height: 100vh !important;`**  to the body area

Comment: Check in devtools by inspecting the element to see what's not full height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style the `<body>` or `<html>` elements of the page, you need to remove the `scoped` attribute of the `<style>` tag. Those elements are outside (the scope of) this component.

Technically, if you don't remove the `scoped` attribute, you are styling any `<body>` or `<html>` tags found inside this component.

Note you can always have

```html
<style scoped>
/* CSS scoped for this component */
</style>

<style>
/* global style (normal CSS) */
</style>
```

More about [scoped CSS here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html).